# how to use createDataFrame to create a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark

I know this is probably to be a stupid question. I have the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
rows = [1,2,3]
df = SparkSession.createDataFrame(rows)
df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

But I got an error:

```
createDataFrame() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'
```

I don't understand why this happens because I already supplied 'data', which is the variable rows.

Thanks

Comment: try `df = SparkSession.createDataFrame(data=rows)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create SparkSession instance using the build pattern and use it for creating dataframe, check
 https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession

```
spark= SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 1):

Below are the steps to [create pyspark dataframe](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/different-ways-to-create-dataframe-in-pyspark/) using createDataFrame

Create sparksession

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()
```

Create data and columns

```
columns = ["language","users_count"]
data = [("Java", "20000"), ("Python", "100000"), ("Scala", "3000")]
```

Creating DataFrame from RDD

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
df= spark.createDataFrame(rdd).toDF(*columns)
```

the second approach, Directly creating dataframe

```
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 
    row = [(1,), (2,), (3,)]
? 
If I am not wrong createDataFrame() takes 2 lists as input: first list is the data and second list is the column names. The data must be a lists of list of tuples, where each tuple is a row of the dataframe.